# Issue with importing a Gradle project for XNAT - unresolved type

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, xnat

I trying to import a Gradle project for XNAT for the first time using Eclipse 2018-12. I created the project, right clicked, chose Gradle then Existing Gradle Project. After the import completed there is an error with SimpleUploadPlugin.java - "The type org.apache.ecs.ConcreteElement cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files". I have checked and I have the commons-lang3-3.8.1.jar.

What do I need to do to resolve this issue please?

My build.gradle dependencies are:

```
// TODO: This is a pretty minimal set of dependencies, so don't worry if you need to add more.
dependencies {
    implementation("org.nrg.xnat:web") {
        transitive = false
    }
    implementation("org.nrg.xnat:xnat-data-models") {
        transitive = false
    }
    implementation("org.nrg.xdat:core") {
        transitive = false
    }
    implementation "org.nrg:prefs"
    implementation "org.nrg:framework"

    implementation("turbine:turbine") {
        transitive = false
    }
    implementation("org.apache.velocity:velocity") {
        transitive = false
    }
    implementation("stratum:stratum") {
        transitive = false
    }

    implementation "log4j:log4j"
    implementation "io.springfox:springfox-swagger2"

    compile group: 'ecs', name: 'ecs', version: '1.4.2'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to change the dependency configuration for **org.nrg.xnat:web** from **compile** or **implementation** to **compileOnly**. This lets you declare fewer dependencies for your plugin because you can allow transitive dependencies. The ECS dependency comes from classes in XNAT itself, so allowing the transitive dependencies means you don't have to declare everything that might be indirectly referenced. I just made this change in the XNAT LDAP authentication plugin and went from this:

```
implementation("org.nrg.xnat:web") {
    transitive = false
}
implementation("org.nrg.xnat:xnat-data-models") {
    transitive = false
}
implementation("org.nrg.xdat:core") {
    transitive = false
}
implementation("org.nrg:prefs") {
    transitive = false
}
implementation("org.nrg:framework") {
    transitive = false
}

implementation "org.springframework:spring-web"
implementation "org.springframework.security:spring-security-config"
implementation "org.springframework.security:spring-security-ldap"

implementation "org.apache.commons:commons-lang3"
implementation "org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api"
implementation "com.google.guava:guava"
implementation "org.slf4j:slf4j-api"
implementation "log4j:log4j"

implementation "org.springframework.security:spring-security-web"
implementation "javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api"

compileOnly "com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305"
compileOnly "org.apache.ivy:ivy:2.4.0"
compileOnly("stratum:stratum") {
    transitive = false
}
```

To this:

```
compileOnly "org.nrg.xnat:web"
compileOnly "org.springframework.security:spring-security-ldap"
compileOnly "org.slf4j:slf4j-nop"
```

If you run this:

```
$ ./gradlew dependencies
```

You'll see that **ecs:ecs:1.4.2** gets pulled in through a number of transitive dependencies.

Comment: Hi Spanky, I commented out all my dependencies (please see edit above) and added you three lines of code. Unfortunately no change.

Comment: Hi Spanky, I found "Refresh Gradle Project" and your code now works. Thanks, Glyn

Answer (score 0):

`org.apache.ecs.ConcreteElement` is from the [Apache Element Construction Set (ECS)](http://jakarta.apache.org/ecs/index.html) and for example contained in [`ecs-1.4.2.jar`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ecs/ecs/1.4.2).

To resolve the issue add a dependency to your `build.gradle` file like the following:

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ecs/ecs
compile group: 'ecs', name: 'ecs', version: '1.4.2'
```

Comment: Can you see the `ecs-1.4.2.jar` (which contains `org.apache.ecs.ConcreteElement`) in the dependencies (in the _Package Explorer_ or _Project Explorer_ view)?